# Network connection usage ( VM and HOST )

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox

let me explain my situation , so i hope you guys can help me out.

I have two wifi connection on my PC. One is build in on m/board , another one is USB adapter.

The build-in wifi is connected to my ISP which have unlimited data that i use for my HOST PC and also Virtual Machine.

The USB Wifi is connected to my HOTSPOT which have very limited data that i'm only use for VIRTUAL MACHINE.

I've already did the Interface metric setting on both connection.
Build in wifi - TCP/ip 4 and 6 - both 1
USB wifi - TCP/ip 4 and 6 - both 100

But the USB WIFI still have some data usage on my HOST PC.
Any idea to solve it ? Like 0 usage on my HOST PC? And make it only work for my virtual machine!
Because my HOTSPOT have very limited data.

The virtual machine i'm running is VIRTUAL BOX.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the USB wireless on the host machine so that only the built in wireless is working.

Now enable USB Pass Through in Virtual Box, and connect the USB wireless in the Guest Machine.

You must enable VBOX Guest Extensions to allow USB Pass Through and to allow the USB device to be used in Virtual Box.

Each machine is unique from any other machine and settings do not carry over. Each machine must be set up individually.

This should accomplish what you want.

Comment: How if  i have 15 virtual machine , 10 virtual running on build in wifi , and another 5 running  on USB ? Can this method works too?

Comment: You have to do USB Pass Through for each machine. That is duplicate the process above for each machine.

Comment: Don't forget that each and every machine is independent of the other. Settings on one machine do not carry over to any other machine. So set up each one individually.

Comment: Ok , i'll give it a try ! Thanks a lot ! :)